# How can I compare two dates in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, date

I'm working on a school project to compare if date1 is equal to date2 - 1 (date1 is one day earlier than date2).

date2 is located one cell below date1. This is will be placed in an if/else statement where the comparison will return a Boolean.

This is the code that I am working on,

```
Sub someLoop()

Dim night As Long
night = 1

Dim c As Long

Dim max_rows As Long

max_rows = UsedRange.Rows.Count

For c = 2 To max_rows
    Range("A" & c).Select
    If ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value2 - 1 Then
        night = night + 1
    Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).SetValue = night
        night = 1
    End If

Next c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Dates in Excel can be treated just like numbers.

So, if [A1] has 28-May-14 and [A2] has 29-May-14, then you can just write the formula: =(A1=A2-1)

Comment: I'm asking how do I do it in a VBA if statement. Right now I am stuck with this, 

"If ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value - 1 Then" 

where ActiveCell.Value = date1 and ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = date2

Comment: Isn't what you've written a VBA statement? If ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value - 1 Then

Perhaps you can use ActiveCell.Value2 to get the underlying number?

Comment: Yes it is a VBA statement but it is not performing what I want

Comment: I think you need to give more details. "it is not performing what I want" is not really enough to go off. Have you tried using .Value2?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [DATEDIFF](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/datediff.php).

For example:

```
dateDiff("d", date2 , date1) = 1
```

With `date2 = 28.05.2014` and `date1 = 29.05.2014`. `d` defines that you want the difference by days.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by [Skiingflea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3685889/skiingflea), Dates in Excel are just numbers, which are counted by 1 day, starting at the first of January 1900, which gives following examples:

```
Date : 01/01/1900 : value 1
Date : 02/01/1900 : value 2
...
Date : 20/04/2023 : value 45036
```

One thing you might be aware of, is the mix of dates and times: times always start at midnight and are calculated as values after the comma:

```
Time : 00h00m00s : value 0
Time : 12h00m00s : value 0.5
Time : 03h20m00s : value 0.13888888...
```

The mixture of dates and times simply consists of adding both together, which means that today at twenty past three, the value will be 45036.13888888...

This also means that, if you want to compare two datetimes, you must take the integer value and those must be equal:

```
Today    at 03h20m00s : value 45036.13888888...
Today    at 12h00m00s : value 45036.5
Tomorrow at 03h20m00s : value 45037.1388888...
```

If, by mistake, you subtract the last two datetimes, you'll see that the value is smaller than 1, which however does not mean that the dates are equal (it's a common mistake).